# PCA(n_components=9) digits Value Error Shape passed values (n, 9), indices imply (n, 10)

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pca

**Problem**

Working on digits data (0-9) and finished coding OneVsOne Classifier and OneVsRest Classifiers for Binary Classification using Multi Class Classification. Code is working on classifiers for machine leaning.

Now ready to add PCA dimension reduction and experiment with results to setup new runs for OneVsOne Classifier and OneVsRest Classifier Multi Class Classification.

Attempting to run PCA(n_components=9) on training model, which is working. Range of digits data is 0-9, hence selection for PCA(n_components=9). The value error reports that the shape of passed values is (16800, 9), while the indices imply (16800, 10).

How can I make this PCA(n_components=9) successfully work with 0-9, essentially shape of (16800, 9) to be matched with indices?

**Shape of Data**

```
train.shape : (16800, 783)
X.shape: (16800, 783)
y (response): (16800,)
```

**Code**

```
principalComponents = model_pca.fit_transform(X)

df_pca = pd.DataFrame(data = principalComponents, 
columns = ['pc0', 'pc1', 'pc2', 'pc3', 'pc4', 'pc5', 'pc6', 'pc7', 'pc8', 'pc9'])

df_pca['targets'] = y_target
```

**Value Error trace**

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (16800, 9), indices imply (16800, 10)

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[142], line 3
      1 principalComponents = model_pca.fit_transform(X)
----> 3 df_pca = pd.DataFrame(data = principalComponents
      4              , columns = ['pc0', 'pc1', 'pc2', 'pc3', 'pc4', 'pc5', 'pc6', 'pc7', 'pc8', 'pc9'])
      6 df_pca['targets'] = y_target

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:694, in DataFrame.__init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    684         mgr = dict_to_mgr(
    685             # error: Item "ndarray" of "Union[ndarray, Series, Index]" has no
    686             # attribute "name"
   (...)
    691             typ=manager,
    692         )
    693     else:
--> 694         mgr = ndarray_to_mgr(
    695             data,
    696             index,
    697             columns,
    698             dtype=dtype,
    699             copy=copy,
    700             typ=manager,
    701         )
    703 # For data is list-like, or Iterable (will consume into list)
    704 elif is_list_like(data):

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py:351, in ndarray_to_mgr(values, index, columns, dtype, copy, typ)
    346 # _prep_ndarray ensures that values.ndim == 2 at this point
    347 index, columns = _get_axes(
    348     values.shape[0], values.shape[1], index=index, columns=columns
    349 )
--> 351 _check_values_indices_shape_match(values, index, columns)
    353 if typ == "array":
    355     if issubclass(values.dtype.type, str):

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py:422, in _check_values_indices_shape_match(values, index, columns)
    420 passed = values.shape
    421 implied = (len(index), len(columns))
--> 422 raise ValueError(f"Shape of passed values is {passed}, indices imply {implied}")
```

Comment: Attempted X_train.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True) before running PCA model fit: model_pca.fit(X_train). However, same value error

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue with aligning to match Shape of passed values with indices imply.

```
df_pca = pd.DataFrame(data = principalComponents, 
        columns = ['pc1', 'pc2', 'pc3', 'pc4', 'pc5', 'pc6', 'pc7', 'pc8', 'pc9'])
```

Of course this was simply an experiment to see that PCA would find under the full feature set of 0-9, not at all what is needed for dimension reduction. So now I am back on track to perform `PCA(n_components=2)` for better outcome.